# R diff -what is the equivalent to D.x in Stata of panel data to generate differenced variables

Tags: r, diff, stata, panel-data

What is the correct syntax to add a differenced variable in R? Similar to the 'D.variable' command in Stata.
I attempt to generate a differenced variable in R. I have tried several ways, but I cannot get the same outputs as Stata.
R code:

```
DF <- DF%>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(D_MDR = F_MDR - dplyr::lag(F_MDR)) 
 summary(DF$D_MDR)
```

Output:

```
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
-0.7724 -0.1456 -0.0098 -0.0113  0.1232  0.8416    1441
```

R code:

```
DFP1 <- pdata.frame(DF, index = c("id"))
DFP1$D_MDR <- diff(DFP1$F_MDR,lag = 1, differences = 1) 
skim(DFP1$D_MDR)
```

Output:

```
-- Data Summary ------------------------
                           Values    
Name                       DFP1$D_MDR
Number of rows             10433     
Number of columns          1         
_______________________              
Column type frequency:               
  numeric                  1         
________________________             
Group variables            None      

-- Variable type: numeric ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# A tibble: 1 x 11
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate    mean    sd     p0    p25      p50   p75  p100 hist 
* <chr>             <int>         <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 data               1441         0.862 -0.0113 0.207 -0.772 -0.146 -0.00978 0.123 0.842 ▁▃▇▂▁
```

Here is the Stata code:

```
 tsset id year
 gen D_MDR = D.F_MDR
 sum D_MDR
```

Stata output:

```
    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
       D_MDR |     11,644    .0067983    .1438224  -.8537842   .8227942
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `diff` from package `plm`, this should get you where you want:

```
DFP1 <- pdata.frame(DF, index = c("id", "year"))
DFP1$D_MDR <- diff(DFP1$F_MDR)
```

Relative to your code, I added the time dimension to `pdata.frame`'s index argument. and I removed the arguments to `diff` (`lag = 1` is default and `difference` is not a valid argument for `plm::diff`).

Note that `plm::diff` tries to shift by time by default (not row-wise, behaviour can be controlled by the `shift` argument), if it can interpret the time dimension correctly (best if you use integer values for the time dimension).